# Can't find variable: Promise in Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am writing test cases with Jasmin.

When I call bellow method,

`initialize({"Data": "primary"});`

Which is:

```
initialize: function(config) {

    console.info("initialize Version 2 initialized..");

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    console.info("promise");

    resolve(true);
    });
}
```

I am getting below error

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise in http://localhost:8080/absolute/home/krushanu/project/krushanu/ekstep/theLib/js-libs/telemetry/telemetry.js?a043c6a23b1af06737d8e1ae1e1c2e152d4faa83`

Installed phantom js Version is `2.1.1`

Comment: that says that Promises are not included in PhantomJS, you may bind a promise polyfill and use it https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-polyfill

Comment: Use chrome headless?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Promise support is not present natively in PhantomJS. 
[See the issue in github here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12401). You could use es6-promise or promise-polyfill to enable Promise support. If it is possible, I would recommend migrating to [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't heard of Puppeteer. That resolved the issue without having to mess with the `promise` polyfill for PhantomJS. It's a better option since I'm using ChromeCanary when debugging anyway.

Comment: @ajaybc Any steps on how to use es6-promise with phantomjs?. Iam using using Phantomjs to generate PDF from HTML file.

Comment: @someITdood I would definitely recommend you to switch to Puppeteer instead of PhantonJS. Since it runs the new version of Chrome behind the scenes it would definitely support whatever support you are looking for.

Comment: @ajaybc But Puppeteer with nodejs or latest chrome standalone requires more than 200 MegaBytes of space.

Comment: I resolved this by adding this js files 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>

https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill