# R/Shiny - Shinytest JS interpreter can not work with Promise and has old JS Standart

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, phantomjs, shinytest

I want to use the R package `shinytest` to test my R/Shiny application. Now, I facing one strange issue after another. It seams that the JavaScript Interpreter of "shinytest" or which runs in the background can not work with `Promise`, neither simple things like `'a'.startsWith('a')` does not work.

**Can I switch the backend of `shinytest` or can I somehow add the missing JavaScript features?**

In the following you see a minimal example, the app itself has no meaning, but the `executing Javascript` inside the test suite shows that simple calls fails.

To run the example you may need to install the "globals" package. Like `renv::install("globals")`.

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinytest)

# you may need to run: 
# renv::install("globals")


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel()
  )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {}


# See above for the definitions of ui and server
app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

testapp <- ShinyDriver$new(app, debug="all")

testapp$executeScript("console.log('Hello')")
print(testapp$getDebugLog("browser"))
testapp$executeScript("console.log('a'.startsWith('b'))")
print(testapp$getDebugLog("browser"))
testapp$executeScript("console.log(Promise)")
print(testapp$getDebugLog("browser"))
```

The last `print` statements should always return correct output. But the error messages are:

```
B/I 12:26:40.26 Hello (:)> testapp$executeScript("console.log('a'.startsWith('b'))")
Error in session_makeRequest(self, private, endpoint, data, params, headers) : 
  undefined is not a function (evaluating ''a'.startsWith('b')')
> print(testapp$getDebugLog("browser"))
> testapp$executeScript("console.log(Promise)")
Error in session_makeRequest(self, private, endpoint, data, params, headers) : 
  Can't find variable: Promise
```

This means that Promises are not available in this `shinytest` package.

Comment: The package is using old `PhantomJS` and Promise is not supported, for solution, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011686/cant-find-variable-promise-in-phantomjs

Comment: Thank you @lz100 for your help. Did you already once switched the backend of shinytest? Besides fixing the missing JS support, is there another recommendation to test UI in shiny like shinytest but with a more modern backend.

Comment: No, I don't use this package often. Maybe you can try [Chromote](https://github.com/rstudio/chromote)